# Why do we not find the right operator overload when using the macro?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading, overload-resolution

I am writing a class template which takes an arbitrary function pointer as non-type template argument. I would like to use

```
template <auto F> struct Foo;
```

but my compiler (MSVC 2017.5) does not support `auto` in the template parameter list (even though it supports many C++17 features). So I wrote a hack around this somehow like this:

```
template <typename T>
using Func = void (*)(T);

template <typename TF, TF F> struct Foo;
template <typename T, Func<T> F> 
struct Foo<Func<T>, F> { ... };

#define FOO(func) Foo<decltype(func), func>
```

I implemented a streaming operator (for `QDebug` or any other text stream) like this:

```
template <typename T, Func<T> F>
QDebug &operator <<(QDebug &out, const FOO(F) &foo)
{
    ...
    return out;
}
```

But my main code cannot find the right `operator<<` overload:

```
void func(int) { ... }

...

FOO(&func) foo;
qDebug() << foo; // error
```

Surprisingly, everything works when defining the operator like

```
QDebug &operator <<(QDebug &out, const Foo<Func<T>, F> &foo)
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It seems that `Func<T>` from this last line and `decltype<F>` from the macro do not give the same type. But I checked this and `std::is_same_v<Func<int>, decltype(&func)>` gives true. I cannot think why using the macro `FOO` gives me any other compile time behavior as when not using it.

---

A minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
using Func = void (*)(T);

template <typename TF, TF F> struct Foo;
template <typename T, Func<T> F> 
struct Foo<Func<T>, F> { };

#define FOO(func) Foo<decltype(func), func>

template <typename T, Func<T> F>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const FOO(F) &foo)
// std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Foo<Func<T>,F> &foo)
{
    return out;
}

void func(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FOO(&func) foo;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl; // error
}
```

Comment: Turn on the preprocessor output for your compiler and see exactly what that `FOO` macro produced.  That is the only way to see up-front what is being compiled.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Isn't it "obvious" that is produces `Foo<decltype(F), F>`? Or what do you mean?

Comment: No, it isn't "obvious".  Macros are evil beasts that can do something you don't expect.  Inspect the preprocessor output -- there is no other substitute to see exactly what the compiler is actually compiling.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Barry I want to learn, so what of this is not satisfied by my code? It contains all you need (remove the `...`), it does not contain more, and it reproduces my problem.

Comment: @M.Winter It's not minimal or complete. You should be able to write a small program that reproduces your problem without, for instance, dependencies on Qt. The separation of code fragments into multiple blocks also makes it difficult to answer, as now we have to gather up the pieces to repro.

Comment: @M.Winter Note that, in this case, since we're dealing with compile (likely, deduction) errors, you don't even have to define your functions to make an mcve. This simplifies your job too.

Comment: @Barry That would be sad. But I tested it with MinGW 5.9.2 right now and got the same problem.

Comment: @M.Winter Anyway, +1, this is now a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the [`template auto` paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html), we also got a new deduction rule in [[temp.deduct.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#13):

> When the value of the argument corresponding to a non-type template parameter `P` that is declared with a dependent type is deduced from an expression, the template parameters in the type of `P` are deduced from the type of the value.

This rule allows the following example to work in C++17, because we can deduce `T` from the type of `V`:

```
template <typename T, T V>
struct constant { };

template <typename T, T V>
void foo(constant<decltype(V), V> ) { }

int main() {
    foo(constant<int, 4>{});
}
```

In C++14 and earlier, this example is ill-formed because `T` isn't deduced. It is precisely this behavior that you are trying to use (implicitly) when you use that macro, which expands into:

```
template <typename T, Func<T> F>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Foo<decltype(F), F> &foo);
```

You are trying to deduce `T` from `F`. Since MSVC doesn't support `template auto` yet, it's perhaps unsurprising that it also doesn't support other parts of the machinery requires to make `template auto` work. And that's the difference between the macro and the non-macro alternative, which can simply deduce `T`:

```
template <typename T, Func<T> F>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Foo<Func<T>,F> &foo)
```

So the simple solution is to just... don't use a macro, since you have a working form, even it's more verbose. A longer solution is to use [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378404/2069064) which side-steps the whole deduction question entirely.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround:

```
template <typename T, Func<T> F> 
struct Foo<Func<T>, F> {
  friend QDebug &operator <<(QDebug &out, const Foo &foo){
    ...
    return out;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When no macro is used second template parameter `F` can be deduced from second function argument `foo`. When macro is used second template parameter `F` can not be deduced from second function argument because it will appear inside of `decltype`: `Foo<decltype(F), F> & foo`. Your code can be simplified to

```
template<typename T>
void f(decltype(T) v){}

int v{};
f(v);
```

Compiler knowns the type of argument (`int`) however template parameter `T` can not be deduced from known type of argument because when used inside of `decltype` `T` must be known at advance.

Comment: Hm. Why is it not obvious to the compiler that `decltype(F)` is `Func<T>` as specified in the template parameter list? Is this some subtlety of how type deduction works?

Comment: @M.Winter At that point compiler does not know that `F` or `T` are yet and tries to deduce them. So deduction stops once compiler encounters something that requires type of template parameter that compiler is trying to deduce to be already known.

Comment: You simplified too far. The other template parameter can be used to deduce too, OP's code is closer to [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CKdANZeuuHmz097q).

Comment: @Barry Other template parameter can not be used to deduce because at that point it is not deduced either. The real problem is use of `decltype`